# Call CSS Class instead of inserting Attribute using JQuery (.css())

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am building a fixed header with using JQuery

Everything is working fine at the moment but instead of setting attributes to classes and I want to call them from css directly. I am not quite familiar with this method.

One of the example is below;

```css
#header-main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 107px;
  color: #8c8c8c;
}
#header-main .sabit{
position : fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 98;
padding-top: 35px;
border-bottom: 3px ridge #7BBD42;
}
```

How I am doing is; ***(Working)***

```
var menu = $('#header-main');
if (...)
    menu.css('position','fixed').css('width','100%').css('z-index','98').css('padding-top','35px').css('border-bottom','3px ridge #7BBD42');
else
    menu.removeAttr('style'); //Back to normal
```

What I am doing to achieve what I want; ***(Not working)***

```
var menu = $('#header-main');
if(...)
    menu.addClass("sabit");
else
    menu.removeClass("sabit"); //Back to normal
```

I also tried `menu.addClass(".sabit");` or `menu.addClass("#header-main .sabit");` but none of them worked.

What part am I doing wrong to add directly css class using JQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not working because you have a space between `#header-main` and `.sabit` in your CSS, meaning that your CSS is trying to style the `.sabit` *descendant* of `#header-main` and not the `#header-main` element itself.

Change:

```css
#header-main .sabit
```

To:

```css
#header-main.sabit
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is fine, the problem comes from your CSS.

The line `#header-main .sabit{` should instead be `#header-main.sabit{`, as the `sabit` class is set on the `#header-main` element and not on one of its children elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
menu.addClass("sabit");
```

to

```
$(menu).addClass("sabit");
```

`addClass` comes from the Jquery library so you need to reference it from there.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, I had a mistake in css part. Thanks!